# How to import an external file from project root with webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, webpack-2

I am building an npm package that will take in custom rules from the project root - similar to the way prettier looks for a `.prettierrc` in the project root.

In my package I am using webpack to compile the build. My app uses react, which I am pulling in externally so that the package is retrieved at runtime instead of being bundled at build time.

webpack.config.js

```
    module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {...},
  module: {...},
  resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve("./src"), path.resolve("./node_modules")],
    alias: {
      react: path.resolve(__dirname, "./node_modules/react"),
      "react-dom": path.resolve(__dirname, "./node_modules/react-dom")
    }
  },
  externals: {
    react: {
      commonjs: "react",
      commonjs2: "react",
      amd: "React",
      root: "React"
    },

    "react-dom": {
      commonjs: "react-dom",
      commonjs2: "react-dom",
      amd: "ReactDOM",
      root: "ReactDOM"
    }
  }
};
```

Here in the `externals` you can see that I am excluding `react` and `react-dom` from the build.

Now, I need a way to import a regular `settings.js` file from the project root, rather than importing a library from the `node_modules`. Does webpack have this capability?

So far I have tried using `externals` to import it like so:

```
externals: {
    react: {...},
    "react-dom": {...},
    "settings": { commonjs: "settings.js" }
  }
```

I know this is wrong, but is there something similar that I can do in order to import an external `.js` file at runtime from the project directory?

Answer (score 11):

I would encourage you to bundle instead of trying to import things at runtime. Webpack is a bundler. Things get messy when you try to work around what its designed to do.

And yes, you can import files outside of the root directory into your bundle. Here is an example from one of my apps that uses external code.

```
{
    test: /\.js?$/,
    include: [
      path.resolve(__dirname),
      path.resolve(__dirname, "../Public/js/src/common")
    ],
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: "babel-loader"
  }
```

I also create an alias.

```
      common: path.resolve(__dirname, "../Public/js/src/common"),
```

Webpack will bundle this file with your app when you import it.

Answer (score 0):

I really needed to load an external json file, actually a settings.json file created by my deployment process that was next to my min.js file generated by webpack. I tried externals, path resolvers, everything that I could imagine and nothing worked.

So finally I ended up doing what I didn't want to do originally, recover the file using fetch (XMLHttpRequest equivalent in typescript). My main worry about this solution was figuring out the url correctly. This can be an issue if you're working in an environment that may involve multiple levels of proxying and sub-paths.

My final solution was to include a script pointing to the file like this in all my root html files (I have multiple):

```html
<script id="very_unique_id" src="settings.json" type="application/json"></script
```

Then from my javascript I loaded that resource and recovered the path:

```js
let element = document.getElementById(ENVIRONMENT_SETTINGS_SCRIPT_ID);
let src = element.src;

let response = await fetch(src);
let settings = await response.json();
```

So, why use the `script` element instead of just building the url? Well basically I wanted to make sure I'm loading the file from the right source, no matter my client's path. We use proxying and normally there's a subpath involved that I don't know from the javascript.

And finally in my webpack config.js file after the plugins and everything I added an externals entry to prevent an error while packing:

```js
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
    ...
    },
    externals: [
        'settings.json'
    ]
}
```

I'm ok with this solution because in the end there's always a fetch involved for any file recovered from the backend, so that's no extra cost. And I'm sure I'm using the right location since I'm using the reference produced by the script tag.

Hope this helps somebody.