# WebPack 1.x - Using a file from outside webpack root

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have this project architecture:

```
Root
    Project1
        package.json
        webpack.config
    Project2
        package.json
        webpack.config
    Common
        file1.js
```

I want to be able to use `file1.js` in side each project.

I am using old `webpack 1.13.1`.

I have tried using an alias:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
      commons: path.resolve(__dirname, ".../../Common/")
    }
}
```

I have tried both ways:

```
import ProcessTree from '../../Common/file1';
import ProcessTree from 'commons/file1';
```

Any ideas?

this is my webpack config:

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import path from 'path';

let commonPath= path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'Common');

export default {
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  entry: [
    './src/index'
  ],
  target: 'web',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist', // Note: Physical files are only output by the production build task `npm run build`.
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      commons: commonPath
    }
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './src'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { 
        test: /\.js$/, 
        include: [
          path.join(__dirname, 'src'), 
          commonPath
        ],
        loaders: ['babel'] 
      },
      { test: /(\.css)$/, loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap'] },
      { test: /(\.scss)$/, loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap', 'sass?sourceMap'] },
      { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file' },
      { test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/, loader: 'url?prefix=font/&limit=5000' },
      { test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream' },
      { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?mimetype=image/svg+xml' }
    ]
  },
  node: {
    fs: "empty",
    child_process: 'empty',
  }
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import an external file from project root with webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54257306/how-to-import-an-external-file-from-project-root-with-webpack)

Comment: I have tested this works with webpack 4, fails with webpack 1

Comment: Did you solve this at the end? Thank you in advance and regards

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the path is included in whichever module loader rule you want to process files within the `Common` folder with.

For example:

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.js?$/,
      include: [
        path.resolve(__dirname),
        path.resolve(__dirname, "../../Common")
      ],
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: "babel-loader"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, updated my question with my webpack.config

Comment: You are adding it in the wrong place - `include` is not a valid top-level configuration property. Add the include to your JS module rule, i.e. like so: `{ test: /\.js$/, include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'), loaders: ['babel'], include: [path.resolve(__dirname, "src"), path.resolve(__dirname, "../../Common")] }`

Comment: corrected, updated my question, still not working, i checked that the resolved path is correct